Autocompletion for cpp in helix editor not working, Ubuntu 24.10
I use Ubuntu 24.10 and I have just installed helix text editor (helix 24.7 (079f5442)). I am new to the editor and I am finding my way out. I have copied and installed in languages.toml the whole lsp for cpp from here. But I have not succeeded in installing the DAP and the Formatter.
hakiza@VBox:~/cpp/ppp/ch02$ helix --health cpp
Configured language servers:
  ✓ clangd: /usr/bin/clangd
Configured debug adapter: lldb-dap
Binary for debug adapter: 'lldb-dap' not found in $PATH
Configured formatter: None
Highlight queries: ✓
Textobject queries: ✓
Indent queries: ✓

When I try to write some ccp code, I can see that the autocompletion is not working. When I open an existing cpp file, I see "Language server exited" message at the bottom left of the window.
How to proceed further to make helix work for cpp environment, when the cpp version is c++20?
Here is the content of my languages.toml file:
[[language]]
name = "cpp"
scope = "source.cpp"
injection-regex = "cpp"
file-types = ["cc", "hh", "c++", "cpp", "hpp", "h", "ipp", "tpp", "cxx", "hxx", "ixx", "txx", "ino", "C", "H", "cu", "cuh", "cppm", "h++", "ii", "inl", { glob = ".hpp.in" }, { glob = ".h.in" }]
comment-token = "//"
block-comment-tokens = { start = "/*", end = "*/" }
language-servers = [ "clangd" ]
indent = { tab-width = 2, unit = "  " }

[language.debugger]
name = "lldb-dap"
transport = "stdio"
command = "lldb-dap"

[[language.debugger.templates]]
name = "binary"
request = "launch"
completion = [ { name = "binary", completion = "filename" } ]
args = { console = "internalConsole", program = "{0}" }

[[language.debugger.templates]]
name = "attach"
request = "attach"
completion = [ "pid" ]
args = { console = "internalConsole", pid = "{0}" }

[[language.debugger.templates]]
name = "gdbserver attach"
request = "attach"
completion = [ { name = "lldb connect url", default = "connect://localhost:3333" }, { name = "file", completion = "filename" }, "pid" ]
args = { console = "internalConsole", attachCommands = [ "platform select remote-gdb-server", "platform connect {0}", "file {1}", "attach {2}" ] }

[[grammar]]
name = "cpp"
source = { git = "https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-cpp", rev = "670404d7c689be1c868a46f919ba2a3912f2b7ef" }

Edited: Here is the content of hx --health
Language   LSP        DAP        Formatter… Highlight… Textobjec… Indent     
ada        ✘ ada_l…   None       None       ✓          ✓          ✘          
           ✘ ada_l…   
adl        None       None       None       ✓          ✓          ✓          
agda       None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
astro      None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
awk        ✘ awk-l…   None       None       ✓          ✓          ✘          
bash       ✘ bash-…   None       None       ✓          ✓          ✓          
bass       ✘ bass     None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
beancount… None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
bibtex     ✘ texla…   None       ✘ bibte…   ✓          ✘          ✘          
bicep      ✘ bicep…   None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
bitbake    ✘ bitba…   None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
blade      None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
blueprint… ✘ bluep…   None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
c          ✓ clang…   ✓ lldb-…   None       ✓          ✓          ✓          
c-sharp    ✘ OmniS…   ✘ netco…   None       ✓          ✓          ✘          
cabal      ✓ haske…   None       None       ✘          ✘          ✘          
cairo      ✘ cairo…   None       None       ✓          ✓          ✓          
capnp      None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✓          
cel        None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
clojure    ✘ cloju…   None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
cmake      ✘ cmake…   None       None       ✓          ✓          ✓          
comment    None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✘          
common-li… ✘ cl-ls…   None       None       ✓          ✘          ✓          
cpon       None       None       None       ✓          ✘          ✓          
cpp        ✓ clang…   ✓ lldb-…   None       ✓          ✓          ✓ 

     

And here is the content of hx --health cpp
hakiza@VBox:~$ hx --health cpp
Configured language servers:
  ✓ clangd: /usr/bin/clangd
Configured debug adapter: lldb-dap
Binary for debug adapter: /usr/bin/lldb-dap
Configured formatter: None
Highlight queries: ✓
Textobject queries: ✓
Indent queries: ✓


I don't think there are something like "--std=c++20" flag for clangd command.
If there are flag like this, you can easily use helix config "[language-server.clangd] args=[]" to launch clangd with the flag.
Therefore, a separate file is needed to provide clangd the compiling information.
Option 1: Generate "compile_commands.json" for clangd
If clangd is being used, generate an compile_commands.json and clangd will see that if that's in "<project_root>" or "<project_root>/build".
I think this is more ideal because you may have other projects need different c++ version or even different toolchain support.

If you are using cmake to build: How to use CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS?

cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=true -Bbuild


If you are using make to build: https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear

bear -- make

Option 2: clangd config
Config path for the project: "<project_root>/.clangd"
Per user global config: "~/.config/clangd/config.yaml"
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-std=c++20]


I come from VS Code and I am new to the Helix editor. I find Helix editor beautiful and appealing, however the documentation is not there (scarcy). I write my cpp codes in Helix and compile using g++ (gcc). My problem is that it seems there is no code autocompleting (intellisense) in Helix for cpp code and wonder if there is a way of fixing it (i.e. making the autocompletion work).

@ezyman Run hx --health you can list the language server that helix expected for each language. For example it's clangd for C++. Once clangd command is in your path, it will be "✓ clangd" in LSP column. In case you want to have a peek first, link: https://docs.helix-editor.com/lang-support.html

If the lsp is failed to start, use helix command ":log-open" to check the log.

I have edited the question and added the content of ´hx --health´. All supported languages have not been included, only languages up to cpp.

To be complete, the only parts of a cpp code that autocompletes are the braces (parentheses and curly braces), the single quotes (for delimiting a character) and the double quotes (for delimiting a string).

@ezyman If clangd is correctly set up, the suggested methods should show up as well. For example it should show append(), assign() ... is available after typing dot after an identifier which type of std::string.

The autocompletion works now. The key word was "If clangd is correctly set up": I removed /purged clangd on my system and reinstalled it again properly. I also added default packages  mentioned at "apt.llvm.org". I appreciate your help and patience :) (I used the second option; global config).
